# Go JSON decoding is very slow. What would be a better way to do it?

Tags: json, go, redis, revel

I am using Go, Revel WAF and Redis.

I have to store large json data in Redis (maybe 20MB).

`json.Unmarshal()` takes about roughly 5 seconds. What would be a better way to do it?

I tried JsonLib, encode/json, ffjson, megajson, but none of them were fast enough.

I thought about using groupcache, but Json is updated in real time.

This is the sample code:

```
package main

import (
 "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
  json "github.com/pquerna/ffjson/ffjson"
)

func main() {
  c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
  defer c.Close()
  pointTable, err := redis.String(c.Do("GET", "data"))
  var hashPoint map[string][]float64
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(pointTable), &hashPoint) //Problem!!!
}
```

Comment: This is the case for profiling. Please read http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs, and, at least, post profile output (if you will not be able to crack it yourself). It will probably help other people to solve your problem.

Comment: "Very slow" compared to... ?

Comment: I'm surprised none of them are fast enough. Could switch to protobufs or build something on `encoding/binary` or write a parser for this JSON. I'm taking your post at face value, but if you haven't profiled or timed so you *know* it's the unmarshal that's slow, I'd verify that.

Comment: If it's taking 5 sec it must be a pretty big structure--maybe you want to store a hash in Redis mapping individual strings to `[]float64`s, so you do a little work each request?

Comment: Thank you everyone.

@twotwotwo
I will try the protobufs or msgpack.

Comment: 20 MB is a huge []byte data. You must profile to make sure part of the time wasn't used on accessing Redis (using hash, list and set make some differences in storing JSON). If you really can't cut down the time any more, why not create another goroutine for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing large JSON data does seem to be slower than it should be. It would be worthwhile to pinpoint the cause and submit a patch to the Go authors.

In the meantime, if you can avoid JSON and use a binary format, you will not only avoid this issue; you will also gain the time your code is now spending parsing ASCII decimal representations of numbers into their binary IEEE 754 equivalents (and possibly introducing rounding errors while doing so.)

If both your sender and receiver are written in Go, I suggest using Go's binary format: [**gob**](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/).

Doing a quick test, generating a map with 2000 entries, each a slice with 1050 simple floats, gives me 20 MB of JSON, which takes 1.16 sec to parse on my machine.

For these quick benchmarks, I take the best of three runs, but I make sure to only measure the actual parsing time, with `t0 := time.Now()` before the Unmarshal call and printing `time.Now().Sub(t0)` after it.

Using GOB, the same map results in 18 MB of data, which takes 115 ms to parse:
 **one tenth the time**.

Your results will vary depending on how many actual floats you have there. If yours floats have a lot of significant digits, deserving their float64 representation, then 20 MB of JSON will contain much fewer than my two million floats. In that case the difference between JSON and GOB will be ever starker.

BTW, this proves that the problem lies indeed in the JSON parser, not in the amount of data to parse, nor in the memory structures to create (because both tests are parsing ~ 20 MB of data and recreating the same slices of floats.) Replacing all the floats with strings in the JSON gives me a parsing time of 1.02 sec, confirming that the conversion from string representation to binary floats does takes a certain time (compared to just moving bytes around) but is not the main culprit.

If the sender and the parser are not both Go, or if you want to squeeze the performance even further than GOB, you should use your own customised binary format, either using Protocol Buffers or manually with "encoding/binary" and friends.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/json-iterator/go

I got 2x decoding speed upgrade comparing to official one, more benefit is jsoniter's APIs are compatible with encoding/json.

Answer (score 0):

Try [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson). It is optimized for speed and usually parses JSON much faster comparing to standard `encoding/json`. Additionally, `fastjson` doesn't need structs adhering JSON schema - a single parser may parse multiple JSONs with distinct schemas.